# Is $\cot^{-1}(-\cot x)$ equal to $-x$?

Tags: trigonometry

I was just wondering: We know that $\cot ^{-1}(\cot x) = x$. But what is the algebraic value of $\cot^{-1}(-\cot x)$?  Is it $-x$?

I am just getting a little muddled up with my trigonometric identities. I would appreciate some clarification.

Comment: It cannot be for any $x$: $\text{arccot}(x)$ is a bounded function while $x$ is not.

Comment: Similarly $\arctan\tan x$ is a sawtooth wave, not the identity function. But course they are the same thing over $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**HINT**

Remember that the cotangent function is odd:
\begin{align*}
\cot(x) = \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)} \Longrightarrow \cot(-x) = \frac{\cos(-x)}{\sin(-x)} = -\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)} = -\cot(x)
\end{align*}

Comment: Ok so it essntially means then $\cot ^{-1} (-\cot x) = x ? $ I get it now Thank you.

Comment: No, you have $\cot^{-1}(-\cot(x)) = \cot^{-1}(\cot(-x)) = -x$.

Answer (score 2):

$$ \cot^{-1}(\cot(x)) = x$$
is not actually a trigonometric 'identity', it is a result of inverse function, $ f(f^{-1}(y)) = y $
$$ \cot( \cot^{-1}(\cot(x)) ) = \cot(x) \implies  \cot^{-1}(\cot(x)) = x $$

by @APC89's answer:
$$ \cot( \cot^{-1}(-\cot(x)) ) = -\cot(x) = \cot(-x) $$
so we have 
$$ \cot^{-1}(-\cot(x))= -x $$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is. Working backwards a bit, we can confirm this.
Remember that $\cos (-x)$ = $\cos (x)$ and $\sin (-x)$ = $-\sin (x)$.

$$\cot^{-1}(-\cot x) = \cot^{-1}\bigg(\frac{\cos (-x)}{\sin (-x)}\bigg) = \cot^{-1} (\cot (-x)) = -x$$